# How can i use beautiful soup to get automatically get what i need from a website?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let's say i have a `.txt` file called `domains.txt` this file has domains i want to test for availability and each on a different line, for example:

```
school.com
math.com
stack.com
jeans.com
```

and i want to test them out on this website https://www.name.com after some research i found that beautiful soup and scrapy would be good for a similar task, scrapy being an overkill so i focused on beautiful soup.

I did some research on how to inspect the web page and found the exact section i'm focusing on in my case i think the search part is :

```
<input id="search-keyword" type="search" name="keyword" value="school.com" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Find your domain name">
```

and the button search that should be clicked after we fill let's say the first element `school.com` is :

```
<button type="submit" id="search-start" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Search" data-ga="event" data-ga-category="Search 6.6" data-ga-action="button" data-ga-label="Search Button"><i class="fa fa-search hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Search</span></button>
```

however i did not manage to understand and replicate the usage of classes and ids and placeholders to do that.

My operating system is windows 8.1.

Comment: so in all the sites in the txt file there's the line `<input id="search-keyword" type="search" name="keyword" value="school.com" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Find your domain name">
` and submit is the same in all the sites `<button type="submit" id="search-start" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Search" data-ga="event" data-ga-category="Search 6.6" data-ga-action="button" data-ga-label="Search Button"><i class="fa fa-search hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Search</span></button>
` ?

Comment: no in the one i shared in the question which is the only one i care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really weird because I don't think you searched on the net. Internet is full of guides and questions like yours already solved. Just search.

---

Anyway, try:

```
div = soup.find(id="search-keyword")
```

to find the element you are looking for with beautifulsoup.

---

But to "click" the submit and to fill the forms, you necessarily need another proper library. Like **selenium**. Here is the guide: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

To search for the element and fill the form:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("search-keyword")
element.send_keys("whateveryouwant")
```

To click submit form:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("search-start").click()
```